# Margin black using iPhone 5C on xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Yesterday I had to change my iphone 4S to 5C and now something is wrong in my xcode app. When I run the app in my iPhone 5C it shows some top and bottom black borders. I have search some on Google and here, but they are talking about put the 3 image launch (and I need help with that).

Any help will be much appreciated, because I'm stuck at the moment and I want to work it for 4 and 5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your app was built prior to iPhone 5 release (which was back in 2012), so the app is quite outdated. **The reason for the black bars on top and bottom is that you do not have a iPhone 5 launch image in the app** and your app is not optimised for iPhone 5 (and newer).

My recommendation is to take a look at iOS 8 and rebuild your user interface to support adaptive layouts, because you will also need to support iPhone 6 and 6+.

Comment: You can go for Xcode 6 GM, which was released on 9th September 2014.